# Why does this exact sequence exist?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I'm reading a proof and don't understand a certain part. Let $A^\bullet$ be a (cochain) complex of abelian groups. Let $I^\bullet$ be an injective resolution of an abelian group $B$. Then there is a short exact sequence 
\begin{equation}
0\to \mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathrm{Ab}}(h^{n+1}(A^\bullet), B)\to h^{-n}(\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet, I^\bullet))\to \mathrm{Hom}(h^n(A^\bullet), B)\to 0.
\end{equation}Moreover, the sequence splits. I don't see where this sequence is coming from. It is given without further attention or reference, so it should be something that is standard or not that hard to see. It does remind me of the Universal Coefficient Theorem, but I am not able to make the link... Any help, proof or reference is appreciated.

Comment: It is related to the universal coefficients theorem, actually some authors even consider this part of the universal coefficients theorem. However it seems you're missing some hypotheses on $A$, are you sure there are not more ?

Comment: In the context I encountered this, it was applied to a specific complex $A^\bullet$. It could well be that this specific complex satisfies the extra hypotheses on $A^\bullet$ you are talking about. Could you tell me what the missing hypotheses are? Do you happen to know a reference for this formulation of Universal Coefficients?

Comment: Usually $A$ is assumed to be a chain complex of free abelian groups or something along those lines. I don't have a reference just right now but I'll come back if this hasn't been answered when I have the time

Comment: What means $h^n$?

Comment: @san $h^n(A^\bullet)$ is the $n$-th cohomology of the complex $A^\bullet$

Comment: I have an idea, but I don't know how to read $A^\bullet$ and $I^\bullet$.

Comment: One could use that $A^\bullet$ is free (or projective)  so that one has an exact sequence of (co)chain complexes $0\to Hom(A^\bullet,B)\to  Hom(A^\bullet,I^\bullet)\to  Hom(A^\bullet,I_{-1})\to 0$, where $I_{-1}$ is the contractible (co) complex with $I_{-1}$ in degree 0 and in degree -1. Then one would have $h^{-n}(\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet, I^\bullet))\cong h^{n}((\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet,B))$, because $h^n( Hom(A^\bullet,I_{-1}))=0$. Then your formula is just the usual UCT. But I am confused about the signs and the whole chain vs. cochain complex definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this old question when viewing my own profile, and thought it might be a good idea to answer it. The exact sequence is indeed just a form of the UCT. The confusion is due to the conventions of chain vs cochain. Very explicit:

For a chain complex $A_\bullet$, write $\phi(A_\bullet)$ for the associated cochain complex. Then $h^{-n}(\phi(A_\bullet)) = h_{n}(A_\bullet)$.

We have $\phi(\mathrm{Hom}(A^\bullet, B)) = \mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet, B[0])$, where $B[0]$ is the cochain complex with $B$ in degree zero and $0$ everywhere else. As $I^\bullet$ is an injective resolution of $B$ we have 
\begin{equation*}
(\star) \ \ \ \ \ \ h_n(\mathrm{Hom}(A^\bullet, B)) = h^{-n}(\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet, B[0])) = h^{-n}(\mathrm{Hom}^\bullet(A^\bullet, I^\bullet)).
\end{equation*}

If $A^\bullet$ is projective, then the UCT gives a split exact sequence 
\begin{equation*}
0\to \mathrm{Ext}^1(h^{n+1}(A^\bullet), B)\to h_n(\mathrm{Hom}(A^\bullet, B))\to \mathrm{Hom}(h^n(A^\bullet), B)\to 0.
\end{equation*}

We now conclude by ($\star$).